# How can I stop input text from writing in 2 inputs?

Tags: html, angular

I have a problem in input text, when I write in one input it changes in the other input as well ! how can I fix that

here is it my code:

```
<mat-expansion-panel  class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled style=" background:#F2EDFF;" *ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie"   >
  <div class="childPanel_body2 mat-badge-large" fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  >
    <div style="padding-left:1em" fxFlex="grow" >{{i.libelle}} {{i.id}}</div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(i.id)">
        <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
        <input  type="text" matInput  formControlName="Note" [(ngModel)]="Note" >
      </form>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**TS File:**

```
Note:string;
    
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    Note: [''],
  });
}
                
onSubmit(id:number) {
  let obj = this.form.value;
  obj.Note = this.Note;

  console.log(this.Note);

  this.LExamenSousCategorieService
    .updateSouCategorie(obj,id)
    .then(res => {});
}
```

Comment: The problem is here `[(ngModel)]="Note"`, you are binding to the same variable. Each one should bind to a different variable if you want different values for each input.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn How can I bind diffrent variable when I have a list ? `*ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie" `

Comment: my guess is you want `[(ngModel)]="i.Note"`, but I am not sure. You will need to also share the relevant component typescript with us.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes I edited my question !

Comment: @drnwork you need to show the `listSousCategorie` variable. It is very hard to help you if you don't provide all relevant information to the problem.

Comment: @DaniloKörber it's a list `  listSousCategorie: any[]=[];` I am getting it from a service

Comment: Still not enough. Of course it is a list, othervise ngFor would't work. Please include an example of a list member, since you are trying to change this member.

Comment: @DaniloKörber Do u mean an example od object from that list  ? ` {id: "69", id_categorie: "1", code: "1", libelle: "science", coefficient: "2", Note: null } `

Comment: "each time you use in the same tag `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName`a little cat die". NOTE: yes, Danilo say you that you should use `[(ngModel)]="i.Note"`. See that the "i" is the variable you put in the loop "*ngFor="let **i** of listSousCategorie". Generally it's used a more representative variable, e,g, "item" and you write "*ngFor="let **item** of listSousCategorie"  and `[NgModel)]="item.Note"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-expansion-panel  class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled style=" background:#F2EDFF;" *ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie"   >
  <div class="childPanel_body2 mat-badge-large" fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  >
    <div style="padding-left:1em" fxFlex="grow" >{{i.libelle}} {{i.id}}</div>
    <mat-form-field>      
      <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
      <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="i.Note">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit(i.id)">
  </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

ts

```
// All commented lines are not needed

// Note:string;
    
// ngOnInit() {
//  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
//    Note: [''],
//  });
// }
                
onSubmit(id:number) {
  // let obj = this.form.value;
  // obj.Note = this.Note;

  console.log(this.listSousCategorie);

  this.LExamenSousCategorieService
    .updateSouCategorie(i.Note,id)
    .then(res => {});
}
```

This is still not the best solution for you, but solves your problem. A better solution would require an extend refactoring.